# Using windows impersonation but getting file access errors

Tags: windows, authentication, iis, impersonation

A coworker of mine create a asp.net web api using c# and iis using windows impersonation in iis for it. It is showing an error: The current identity (domain\username) does not have write access to 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files'
I don't want to change anything server related, but I am ok with changing iis settings relating to this website and any code that is needed. Any thoughts?

Comment: This error means the permission issue with the domain\username. The most easily way to solve this is use ASP.NET IIS Registration Tool  to grant the domain\username  access to the IIS metabase and other directories that are used by ASP.NET.  You could use CMD to run this command: aspnet_regiis.exe -ga "DOMAIN\USERNAME".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I looked deeper and I had ASP.NET Impersonation and Windows Authentication enabled at the same time. What I found out, was to have the app pool run as the account I wanted the code to impersonate and disable ASP.NET Impersonation and leave windows auth enabled.